# Omitting do/does

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs, subordinate-clauses, interrogatives, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I came across one of the questions founded in the **TOEFL**.

> *... is entirely up to him*

(The correct answer)

-*How he travels*

(what I choose)

-*How is he traveling*

(what I thought to be correct, but didn't appear as an option )

-*How does he travel*

How could the third clause above didn't appear in the question? And it's a common sense for me to just say the first sentence above is correct but since I just followed the writing rules and couldn't even explain why I feel it's correct so I chose the second sentence.

I know that I can omit modal (*do/does*) in **Wh-** question, like '*who wants to be...*', but 'how he travels...' is completely unrelated since there is '*he*' there.

Is there any specific information on this topic in English grammar? What do we call it? Is it just fixed pattern? Perhaps it might be considered to be easy, but I miss this kind of things like a lot times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be correct, "How is he travelling ..." should be re-ordered to "How he is travelling ..." in this situation.  It is then *equally as correct* as "How he travels..."

"How does he travel..." is wrong in this situation, as "how" is being used as a conjunction between the two clauses. The sentence could equally be written as "It is entirely up to him how he travels."  This re-ordering of the sentence makes it clearer that "how" is being used as a conjunction.

How can also used to ask a question, e.g. "How does he do it?" or "How does he travel?". Whenever "how" is being used to ask a question, it is acting like the  "**Wh-**" words - what, when, where, why, who.

As Rudyard Kipling once wrote:

> I KEEP six honest serving-men
>    (They taught me all I knew);
>   Their names are What and Why and When
>    And How and Where and Who.